# SSRS CRP Error: The permissions granted to user '' are insufficient for performing this operation

Tags: caching, sharepoint, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008-r2

When trying to run a cache refresh plan for a Shared Data set on SharePoint (2010) Integrated SSRS 2008 R2, I receive the following message:

Error:

> The permissions granted to user '' are insufficient for performing
>   this operation..

It appears that the request may not be passing along any user / credential information, but not sure if this is what is actually happening and even if it is, how I would correct this.

The Shared Data set was created in Visual Studio 2010 and deployed into a SharePoint SSRS Report Library. I can run the reports that use this Shared Data set without any issues, my only problem is getting the CRP (Cache Refresh Plan) to work.

Any assistance that can be offered is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: are the database connections being made by the service account, person whom is browsing account, or what else?

Comment: The DB connection is being made by a service account whose credentials are stored with the Shared Data Source that the Shared Dataset uses.